# How convert activity to fragment

Tags: android

How I can convert this to `Fragment` to use `ViewPager`?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {

       view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent,    false);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       assert view != null;
       holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
       holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
       view.setTag(holder);
           // ......
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples for implementing ViewPager [ViewPager Tutotial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html)  &                  [ViewPager with FragmentPageAdapter](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

Comment: Thank you very much...But i cant find out.I've added getActivity().getLayoutInflater() and it error 

E/AndroidRuntime(20849): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.GridView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
E/AndroidRuntime(20849):  at com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.Japan.onCreateView(Japan.java:82)
E/AndroidRuntime(20849):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
 E/AndroidRuntime(20849):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)

Comment: Clean the project. I often have errors within XML when the different views are cast to each other. That should do it.

Comment: was my answer helpful?